# Why is [Op.and] not working in this instance using Sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a table of Images, each Image has many Tags (note - each Tag is a separate row in the Tags table, which contains the Tag name and a confidence value - so this means many different rows of the same tag text, e.g. "cat" can exist, each with a different confidence value.

I want to find query all Images where 2 or more Tags are included. Find all Images that have the tag name "cat" AND "dog".

MODELS

```
const Tag = sequelize.define("tag", {
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT('tiny')
        },
        value: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
    });

const Frame = sequelize.define("frame", {
        location: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    });
```

RELATIONS

```
db.projects.hasMany(db.frames, { onDelete: 'CASCADE', hooks: true })
db.frames.belongsTo(db.projects, {
    foreignKey: "projectId",
    as: "project"
});

db.frames.hasMany(db.tags, { onDelete: 'CASCADE', hooks: true });
db.tags.belongsTo(db.frames, {
    foreignKey: "frameId",
    as: "frame",
})
module.exports = db;
```

CONTROLLER

```
// form query (search?tags=cat;dog) into an array
var tagQuery = req.query.tag.split(";")

// form query
Frame.findAll({
            include: {
                model: Tag,
                where: {
                    name: {
                        [Op.and]: tagQuery
                    }
                },

            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            res.json(data)
        })
```

The expected behaviour is that only Frames that match both "cat" AND "dog" are returned. Actual behaviour is that no frames are returned, even if the records have both "cat" and "dog"

Changing

```
[Op.and]
```

to

```
[Op.any]
```

Has the expected behaviour of returning all frames that have any of the matching terms in the query.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED

Using

```
[Op.overlap]
```

Which results in the following error:

```
error: SequelizeDatabaseError: operator does not exist: text && text[]
```

Changing the Tag name type to STRING, makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to check that a certain frame has ALL indicated tags you should do a subquery in the main `where` option and not in `where` option inside `include` option:

```
where: sequelize.where(sequelize.literal(`
(SELECT count(*) 
 from tags 
 where tags.frameId=frame.id 
   and tags.name IN (<place all tags here in single quotes separated by comma>)
)`), '=', tagQuery.length)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225099/discussion-on-answer-by-anatoly-why-is-op-and-not-working-in-this-instance-usi).